# loop variable shows garbage value

Tags: c, linked-list

I was writing a program to give back a string having the concatenation of all the strings in the nodes of a linked list till the total size of the concatenated string is not equal to a a particular number of bytes. But the value of the loop variable becomes garbage in the last iteration. Can anyone tell me why?

```
typedef struct li {
    char *data;
    int len;              //structure for the linked list
    struct li *next;
} node ;

node *head;


void create()
{
     int i,n;
     char num[100];               //the value of i when equal to n-1 becomes garbage
                                   //of the proper n-1
     node *temp;
     printf("enter the number of nodes\n");
     scanf("%d",&n);             //supposed to create the list
     printf("n=%d",n);
     printf("enter the strings to be kept in the nodes\n");

     for(i=0;i<n;i++) {

         if(i==0) {
             head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
             temp=head;
         }
         else {
             temp->next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
             temp=temp->next;
         }

         scanf("%s",num);
         temp->data=num;
         temp->len=strlen(num);
         //in the final loop shows error as value of i becomes garbage
     }
     temp->next=NULL;
}


void g(int n)
{
    int t=0,m;     //the main logic
    char *f={'\0'};
    node *temp;
    temp=head;

    while(temp!=NULL && t!=n) {
        m=sizeof(temp->data);
        strcat(f,temp->data);
        t+=m;
        temp=temp->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a memory leak. When the last node is allocated, you still allocate `temp->next` and then you just assign `NULL` to `temp->next` without deallocating the memory.

Comment: In function `g()`, you probably need to use `strlen(temp->data)` instead of `sizeof(temp->data)` as the value of `sizeof()` is a compile time constant and you're concatenating variable length strings.  You also need to allocate storage for `f` in the function, probably via `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

You use `scanf` to read a string from the user, and put it in a local array. The first problem is that you make *all* node pointer point to this local array. The second problem is that it's a *local* variable that won't be valid once the function return.

The simplest way to solve this is to use the `strdup` function to duplicate the string. Just remember that you then have to `free` that text.